# Open .fig file and delete some of the plot entries-Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, matplotlib, figure

I have the following image stored as f7.fig. I want to open it again and delete all the other entries except the first (red), second (blue) and last(cyan). I want also to delete them from the legend. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy interactive approach would be like this:

```
savefig(h, 'somefig.fig`); % Save figure
% Close the figure ...
openfig('somefig.fig'); % Open figure
% Click on the curves you wanted to delete ....
delete(gco); % delete object -> this takes care of the legend too
% Click on the curves you wanted to delete ....
delete(gco); 
% so on...
```

This approach [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/308248-make-lines-visible-or-invisible#answer_239898) is also an alternative.